# Merged pull request showing as open in Search results

Tags: github, pull-request

I use a search criteria to filter my PRs to display all the open PRs. It's worked perfectly in the past, but now it has started showing a some merged PRs.

My search criteria:

```
is:open is:pr org:trailhead
```

results in this:

[image: image of the search results]

It includes three merged PRs. I've tried to add labels and then use search to exclude these PRs, but that's not working either (they stay in the list).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18):

I has a similar issue, removing the assignees who haven't neither approved nor requested changes fixed the issue

Comment: Just had this as well, self-assigned and it went away

Comment: In my case, there was no assignee but self-assigning myself as @spences10 suggests worked for me as well (even after un-assigning immediately again).

Comment: FWIW, adding a reviewer and removing it immediately worked also.